# which function does VLC use to open a video file?

Tags: video, vlc, libvlc, video-codecs

i`ve downloaded a video file and recorded the packet arrival time. and i want to use VLC to play the video according to the time i record. which function and how should i call to do it in the VLC source code?

i mean usually which functions VLC use to play video when we press the button to open a video file? because there are so many files and functions in its source tree.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can just link to libVLC and call functions in it.
http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_Thumbnailer gives an example of a small C program that uses this technique to open a movie, seek to a time within the movie, grab a JPG of one frame, and save it to disk. It is only a few lines of code.

I don't know about Windows, but on Mac, the header and shared library are at:
in the VLC application package at: VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/include/vlc/vlc.h (and the other .h files in that directory) and the library is at VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlc.dylib

Note that the library is GPLv2, not LGPL. My understand is that if you link to the library, you are required to release your program as GPL.

Comment: Thanks, I have traced VLC and found it out. I think it should be in input module.