# which development software should be used for VLC on mac?

Tags: c, macos, development-environment, vlc, libvlc

i want to do some modification and development for VLC. i download its source code, vlc-1.1.5. and it is written by C. so usually which development environment should i use, xcode or some others?

thx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought VLC was developed in [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). Do you see the class names starting with Q? In case it is developed in Qt, [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads#qt-creator) or [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) would be a good choice of development environment.

Comment: Whether you do or not, how does this help determine how to set up your development environment?

Comment: If you see it is developed in Qt, use Qt Creator as your development environment.

Comment: You're right; that's an interesting idea that I hadn't even considered. You should update your answer with that suggestion more explicitly (and perhaps a link to download Qt Creator), and I'll upvote.

Comment: Yes, it has a qt4 directory in the path /modules/gui/, I`ll have a try, Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

The VideoLAN folks provide a wiki page with information about compiling their source on multiple platforms. The page relevant to OS X is here: http://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile

> Compiling VLC media player on Mac OS X is different from normal linux compiling and OS X compiling. We do not use Xcode, but a simple ./configure and then make isn't enough either.

The page provides a step-by-step guide to setting up a machine running either OS X 10.5 or 10.6.

Comment: i try to read its source code, but find that it is too complicated to understand if without a development environment. such as my another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789825/which-function-does-vlc-use-to-open-a-video-file

Comment: @JavaMobile: I've never seen a development environment that interpreted code for me. Is there such a thing? Have I been doing entirely too much of the hard work myself?

Answer (score 0):

Any editor of choice should suffice. Looking at the code, it seems that VLC uses Unix-style building (autotools, make, etc). On Win32, it uses MinGW, so plain old gcc and make is probably used on OSX as well.